# Actualizing working copies from git repository

Tags: git, github, push, pull

I have 2 identical working copies named WC1 and WC2. I have made some changes to WC1 and pushed it to my repository on Git Hub. Now I want to pull the changes to WC2 but git says "Already up to date" while it's not. [image][image]

I am super new to git and not really understand what I am doing wrong

Comment: Do the 2 local repositories have the same remote that points to the same Github repository? What command did you run to update WC2?